# vtkInteractorStyleRubberBandPick: Set selection mode without pressing key

Tags: pyqt, vtk

The class vtkInteractorStyleRubberBandPick allows selection of a rectangular window, when 'r' is pressed, and selection of a 1x1 window, when 'p' is pressed.

1. Is there a way to get the key that is currently pressed (the current selection mode)?
2. Is it possible to set the selection mode 'r' or 'p' in the code (i'm using pyqt and would like to choose the mode by checking a box in a gui)?

Answer (score 1):

I don't speak python, so I don't know what extra obstacles you will have, but in c++ you could do this:

ad 1) the picking mode is not publicly accesible, it is represented by a protected variable `CurrentMode`  (see the c++ [source code](https://github.com/Kitware/VTK/blob/master/Interaction/Style/vtkInteractorStyleRubberBandPick.h)). You would have to create your own class derived from vtkInteractorStyleRubberBandPick and define new public method for it that would return the mode.

ad 2) Again, not directly. But if you were to derive your own class anyway, you could also define your own method for setting the mode, as there is none. Without it, I suppose you could have your check box give focus to the vtk window and fire an R-key-pressed event...sounds overly complicated, but it would probably work.

Comment: I'm a bit lost with the python wrapping of the original code. In python, the class vtkInteractorStyleRubberBandPick doesn't have a variable CurrentMode, or it is somehow hidden. I tried to create a subclass MyInteractorStyle that would modify the mode (by calling super(MyInteractorStyle,self).CurrentMode = 1), but that didn't work.

Comment: It's possible the names of the variables are mangled somehow, I think the "standard" in python is to put underscores in front of the variable name to "mark" them as private/protected, maybe the vtk wrapper is doing that? There is a readme on the wrapper: https://github.com/Kitware/VTK/blob/master/Wrapping/Python/README.md , it shows how to print the built-in documentation, perhaps it will show you the name of the variable (if it is wrapped at all). Sorry, I probably can't help you more, maybe try the vtk mailing list if this doesn't help.